# Subclassing in Rails models and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance

I am programming an e-commerce type web app (not exactly, but to give you an idea). I will be displaying different types of products that have little to do with one another, but I would like to have a Product parent class, to have a common view for all the subclasses, and share some fields and behaviours.

But this raises many questions to me, specially regarding to ActiveModel: Product shouldnt have its own table, but I would want some fields in its subclasses (hotel, restaurant, etc) to inherit those fields from it. How would I go about that?

Another reason to have a Product parent class would be that eventually I will need to use Product.all and different scopes of the class objects.

Maybe I am totally misguided, so feel free to suggest any way to do this. Maybe using a module?

Comment: what about single table inheritance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, inheritance implies that fields are inherited; therefore, you don't just a get **some fields** you get **all** the fields for the parent class in the subclass.

You can achieve what you want in multiple ways:

- Create a module and place all your shared methods in it, and include it in each model
- Use `set_table_name` in the subclass to route the model to use another table. This is useful if you have multiple tables that share the same fields as your `product` table.
- If your models share the same table, but are distinguished by, say, an attribute such as `product_type` you can use `default_scope` to always apply a condition such as `default_scope where(:product_type => :hotel)`

Use the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org) as a reference for the use of the aforementioned methods.